# Facebook session dissappears when refreshing the webpage

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm new to the facebook login SDK for PHP and i'm trying to create a "log in with facebook" function on my website.

I'm using this code which works great:

```
session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app-id', 'app-secret');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'app-redirect-link' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

If I press "Login" I get my details and everything I need, but as soon as i'm refreshing the page - the "Login" link appears again, as if the session does not exist anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to store the session somewhere, and load it if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a new session and using it helped.